# Use Navigator in main.dart get current context

Tags: flutter, navigator

Is there some chance to get current context on the main.dart? I am using the sharing intent for listening applinks, and I need to redirect to specify page. But I don't know how can I use the context.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialText().then((String val){
   //some logic
   Navigator.pushNamed(context, ....);
  });

  return MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        initialRoute: Routes.home,
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          switch (settings.name) {
             case Routes.home:
             return SimplePageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen());
             break;
          }
        }
   );
  }
```

I have got this error

> Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that
>   does not include a Navigator.

Ok I am understand, but how can I get the current context in this place?

Comment: Why do you want to have the context before running the materialApp?

Comment: Because I need to set some base listeners which is global, and the great place I think is main.dart

Comment: @PetrKlein yes I got it working with navigatorkey. But I am using GoRouter which does not use navigatorkey. Thoughts on the same?  I also have a listener in main()

Answer (score 3):

Ok I fixed it with **navigatorKey**!!

```
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialText().then((String val){
   //some logic
   navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(Routes.myPage);
  });

  return MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        initialRoute: Routes.home,
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
           switch (settings.name) {
           case Routes.home:
           return SimplePageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen());
           break;
          }
        }
   );
  }
```